# pre-commit InvalidConfigError

Tags: pre-commit-hook, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

When I want to commit my changes in the `.pre-commit-config.yaml`, I get the following error:

```
An error has occurred: InvalidConfigError: 
==> File .pre-commit-config.yaml
=====> while parsing a block mapping
  in "<unicode string>", line 33, column 3
did not find expected key
  in "<unicode string>", line 34, column 3
Check the log at /Users/name/.cache/pre-commit/pre-commit.log
```

The lines 33+ are:

```
- repo: local
  - id: pytest
    name: Run tests (pytest)
    entry: pytest -x
    language: system
    types: [python]
    pass_filenames: false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed adding "hooks" to the file, now it works:

```
- repo: local
  hooks:  # <- this was missing
  - id: pytest
    name: Run tests (pytest)
    entry: pytest -x
    language: system
    types: [python]
    pass_filenames: false
```